# VBA - 1 Button which calls a specific sub at specified times

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Hoping someone out there can help me achieve a simple way to automate copying and pasting at specific times from different cells.

Its my first time using Case and I'm not sure if this is even the best way to go about achieving my goal. Essentially I want to copy from one worksheet and paste to another using one button. This is simple enough but I only want that button to run one of four different variations at specified times. So far I have the following:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng As Range

   Refresh.All

   DoEvents

   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set rng = Application.Range("Display!B80")

   Select Case rng.Time(Now)

       Case #5:00:00 AM# To #8:55:00 AM#:
            Call Module1

        Case #8:55:01 AM# To #11:25:00 AM#:
            Call Module1

        Case #12:00:00 AM# To #2:55:00 PM#:
            Call Module1

        Case #2:55:01 PM# To #6:00:00 PM#:
            Call Module1

    End Select
End Sub
```

"Display!B80" = (**current time**-INT(**current time**))*24 formatted by HH:MM:SS

Module1 contains a Sub called Quarter1()

which contains a bunch of lines consisting of:

```
Range("B16")
Worksheets("Main").Range("D2").Copy
Worksheets("Display").Range("B16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("B16")
```

This copying and pasting works as needed, I just can't get the button click to run without an error. Is what I'm attempting even possible or am I way off with my approach?

Comment: Can you post the error your getting ?

Comment: Just change   Select Case rng.Time(Now) to be Select Case Time()

Comment: Error I'm receiving is:  Expected Variable or procedure, not module. Changing the line to Case Time() resulted in the same error.

Comment: You can't `Call Module1`, a module can't be called, ...which is exactly what the error message is telling you; you call a *procedure*, not its module... If you mean to "call" `Module1.Quarter1` then do `Module1.Quarter1` (FWIW there hasn't been a need for that `Call` keyword for over 20 years)

Comment: I did not know that, appreciate the new information, thank you. I've changed the line to just Module1.Quarter1 and get the error "Object Required".  I've made sure everything is correctly named. I greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Do you have a module *actually named* `Module1`? A *standard module* (not a *class* module)?

Comment: BTW `Range("B16")` is not a legal instruction (it does nothing), so exactly where is "object required" being raised?

Comment: The module is named Module1 with a Sub Quarter1(). I apologize the correct range is: 

        Range("B16:C18").UnMerge
        Worksheets("Main").Range("D2").Copy
        Worksheets("Display").Range("B16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("B16:C18").Merge